# ReflectionException in Route.php line 333: Method App\Http\Controllers\DbImportController::csv() does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 and facing strange behavior at local and server.
The below code working fine in Local where as not working in server.

In controller newly added method is not working, even updating the existing method also not working.

Routing code

```
routes\web.php code as below

Route::get('dbimport/','DbImportController@index');
Route::get('dbimport/test','DbImportController@test');
```

DbImportController code

```
app\Http\Controllers\DbImportController.php as below

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use \Illuminate\Database\Connection;
use \Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

class DbImportController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return view('dbimport');
    }

    public function test() {
        return 'This is a test method';
    }
}
```

The above code is working fine and the methods also working fine, but today I added new method which is called csv and updated test method content.

Updated code as follows

```
class DbImportController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return view('dbimport');
    }

    public function test() {
        return 'This is a test method modified @ 27/10/2016';
    }

    public function csv() {
        return view('csvimport');
    }
}
```

And routes/web.php

```
Route::get('dbimport/','DbImportController@index');
Route::get('dbimport/test','DbImportController@test');
Route::get('dbimport/csv','DbImportController@csv');
```

Now, if I run the test method it's showing old content as "This is a test method" not showing updated code.

If I run the new method dbimport/csv it's showing an error as below
[image]

I run all the following cache clear commans,

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

But no use.

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating `routes/web.php` to:

```
Route::get('dbimport/csv','DbImportController@csv');
Route::get('dbimport/test','DbImportController@test');
Route::get('dbimport/','DbImportController@index');
```